# rpy2 : Korean characters are not working on rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

python code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

rCommand='''gender <- c("남자", "남자", "남자", "여자", "여자", "여자", "여자", "여자")
  age    <- c(23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37)
  outdf <- data.frame(gender, age)
'''
robjects.r(rCommand)
resultDf_r=robjects.globalenv["outdf"]

print type(resultDf_r)
```

Korean characters makes the python.exe killed.

In R command terminal, "rCommand" above works well.

I couldn't find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

my env: window 7 x64, python 2.7.8 x64, rpy2 2.5.4, R 3.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing, there is unfortunately no official support of `rpy2` for windows. The code snippet you are providing is working fine on Linux.

Your options might be:

- run your code in a Linux VM (or container - MS has announced to be backing Docker)
- submit a patch for rpy2
- file a bug report on the bitbucket page for `rpy2` hoping that this translates into a patch by someone

**Edit:** The comments suggest that helping out Python 2.7 with encoding might help (no promise - everything is working on Linux so this might be Windows-specific). A string can be explicitly specified to be in unicode with (note the prefix `u` before `'''`):

```
rCommand=u'''
    gender <- c("남자", "남자", "남자", "여자", "여자", "여자", "여자", "여자")
    age    <- c(23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37)
    outdf <- data.frame(gender, age)
'''
robjects.r(rCommand)
```

Comment: Now I found bypass. 1. R command save to script.R , 2. I execute R command => source("c:\\script.R")  It works well with Korean chars.

Comment: source("c:\\script.R") ==> source("c:\\script.R", , encoding='UTF-8-BOM' )

Comment: I am only seeing now that you are using Python 2.7, not 3.4. You'll almost certainly need to specify the encoding when working in Python. Switching to  Python 3.4 (and unicode by default) might be a good idea in general.

Comment: I wrote encoding option first like "#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-'" . I am not good at writing in English. Thank you for your careful reply. (From Korea Seoul)

Comment: I mean the encoding for the string containing R code. I have edited the answer to add an example.