# Pandas convert_to_r_dataframe function KeyError

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, rpy2

I create a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray(), columns = colnames)
```

Then I convert it to a R dataframe:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com

rdf = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
```

Under Windows with this configuration there are no problems:

```
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.7.final.0
python-bits: 32
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: AMD64 Family 16 Model 4
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.14.1
numpy: 1.8.2
rpy2: 2.4.4
...
```

But when I execute it on Linux with this configuration:

```
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.2.0-29-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.14.1
numpy: 1.8.2
rpy2: 2.4.4
...
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 232, in <module>
    clf.global_cl(df, df2)
  File "/home/uzer/app/util/clftool.py", line 202, in global_cl
    rdf = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
  File "/home/uzer/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/rpy/common.py", line 324, in convert_to_r_dataframe
    value = VECTOR_TYPES[value_type](value)
KeyError: <type 'numpy.int64'>
```

It seems that VECTOR_TYPES does not have `<type 'numpy.int64'>` as key. But this is not true:

```
VECTOR_TYPES = {np.float64: robj.FloatVector,
            np.float32: robj.FloatVector,
            np.float: robj.FloatVector,
            np.int: robj.IntVector,
            np.int32: robj.IntVector,
            np.int64: robj.IntVector,
            np.object_: robj.StrVector,
            np.str: robj.StrVector,
            np.bool: robj.BoolVector}
```

So I printed variable type in `convert_to_r_dataframe` (in `../pandas/rpy/common.py`):

```
for column in df:
    value = df[column]
    value_type = value.dtype.type
    print("value_type: %s") % value_type
    if value_type == np.datetime64:
        value = convert_to_r_posixct(value)
    else:
        value = [item if pd.notnull(item) else NA_TYPES[value_type]
                 for item in value]
        print("Is value_type == np.int64: %s") % (value_type is np.int64)
        value = VECTOR_TYPES[value_type](value)
        ...
```

And that's the result:

```
value_type: <type 'numpy.int64'>
Is value_type == np.int64: False
```

How can it be possible?? Given that the 32 bit Windows version has no problems, could be a problem with the 64 bit Linux Python version?

**EDIT:** Suggested by @lgautier, I modified this:

```
rdf = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
```

to:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
rdf = pandas2ri.pandas2ri(df)
```

And that worked.

**NOTE**: My dataframe contains utf-8 special characters, as column names, decoded in unicode. When `DataFrame` constructor is called (contained in `rpy2/robjects/vectors.py`), this line try to encode the unicode string (that contain special characters) to an ascii string:

```
kv = [(str(k), conversion.py2ri(obj[k])) for k in obj]
```

This generate an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To solve this I had to change that line in:

```
kv = [(k.encode('UTF-8'), conversion.py2ri(obj[k])) for k in obj]
```

Rpy2 should introduce a method that allows to change the encoding.

Comment: After looking closer at the code, the use of `str(k)` is also not completely consistent. A quick fix would be to add this as a parameter to the `DataFrame` constructor but this would not completely solve the problem.  May be this is just the kind of headache the massive change of string handling in Python 3 is addressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using rpy2's own conversion (which appear to be working with `int64` on Linux):

```
# create a test DataFrame
import numpy
import pandas

i2d = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype="int64")
colnames = ('a', 'b', 'c')
dataf = pandas.DataFrame(i2d, 
                         columns = colnames)

# rpy2's conversion of pandas objects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

Now pandas DataFrame objects will be converted automatically
to rpy2/R DataFrame objects on each call using the embedded R.
For example:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
# R's "base" package
base = importr('base')
# call the R function "summary"
print(base.summary(dataf))
```

One can also call the conversion explicitly:

```
from rpy2.robjects import conversion
rpy2_dataf = conversion.py2ro(dataf)
```

**edit:** (added customization to work around the `str(k)` issue)

Should anything related to the conversion be requiring local customization, this can be achieved relatively easily. One way
to change the way the R `DataFrame` is built is:

```
import pandas.DataFrame as PandasDataFrame
import rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame as RDataFrame
from rpy2 import rinterface
@conversion.py2ro.register(PandasDataFrame)
def py2ro_pandasdataframe(obj):
    ri_dataf = conversion.py2ri(obj)
    # cast down to an R list (goes through a different code path
    # in the DataFrame constructor, avoiding `str(k)`) 
    ri_list = rinterface.SexpVector(ri_dataf)
    return RDataFrame(ri_list)
```

From now on, the conversion function above will be used when a pandas
`DataFrame` is present:

```
rpy2_dataf = conversion.py2ro(dataf)
```

Comment: I need to call the conversion explicitly, so I tried: `conversion.py2ro(df)` or alternately `pandas2ri.pandas2ri(df)` but they result in: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`. This is probably due to column/row names that need encoding in 'UTF-8' and not in 'ascii'. There is a way to force UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @MrMoog - It is hard to reproduce without a full example. There was a recent report of encoding issues that appear Windows-specific ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247851/rpy2-korean-characters-are-not-working-on-rpy2 ). It would be interesting to see if this is a related issue.

Comment: I forgot that rpy2 has a lack. In the `DataFrame` constructor (in `rpy2/robjects/vectors.py`), strings are automatically converted to ascii. In my dataframe there are unicode strings with special characters (originated from UTF-8 encoding) as column names. I had to change `kv = [(str(k), conversion.py2ri(obj[k])) for k in obj]` to `kv = [(k.encode('UTF-8'), conversion.py2ri(obj[k])) for k in obj]`

Comment: Strings are not converted to ASCII. As shown in the code you quote, the string representation (method `str`) as defined in the Python running is used. It happens that in Python 2 strings are bytes. There is may be a way to make a Python 2-specific patch, but I'd rather recommend to change the default encoding (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python), or move to Python 3.